# zxing custom interface --Android

Tags: android

I am new to zxing integration. I can able to scan and generate qr codes. Now I need to update the zxing surfaceview with header and footer. The zxing used `onDraw` to draw the transparency later with red line mark over thee. But I want to include buttons over the camera screen. Right now I used framelayout, inside that I given the surfaceview and zxing overlay view. Can anyone guide me how to place custom header in zxing lib.

Comment: Use [zbar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android) instead for advanced cusomizations and for better performance.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I already done my entire flow with zxing. Only pending is customize the Ui. Any idea to custom the surfaceview.